# How to get insights of app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am beginner in android app development, I would like to know that how can i get insights of something that has been implemented, Which layout is used, Which view is it, I try to make some attractive UI and i end-up with some ugly UI, I would like to know how they make UI like this [image]

[image]

[image]

Which layout they use, Which view they use, I Want to know this insights so that i can learn about them and implement the same in my app.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this by using `Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator` option in **Eclipse** for that

1. Go to `DDMS` and `devices`and select the device

   [image]
2. and then it's generate your device screen shot .`uix` as below

[image]

Move your Cursor in `uix` and you'll see the all `View Hierarchy Structure` in right side upper corner area.

Here you'll get idea about the `Layout View` only.

Answer (score 0):

@Pushpendra you will never get exactly what you want, you can get some ideas by seeing some existing application and then google it or check some open source projects on github to get starting idea.
You have to use your own creativity.
Here is a basic example to help you start.
Use this library 
**[cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)** 
which will help you to built card style layout as some of your shared images UI is designed the same way. 
[**Sample app demo**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.gmariotti.cardslib.demo.extras&hl=en)
for above library.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to how the view is draw, you can go in the "Developer Options" settings and enable the "Show layout bounds" item.

If you want a more in-depth view of the layout, on the SDK you have the "Hierarchy View" that can be accessed from command line or on Eclipse/Android Studio. Inside Hierarchy View, go to the screen you want to know in the phone, select the screen in Hierarchy View and after a while the entire layout tree is shown and you can explore the items in it, so you can have an idea about the layout.